# Allow specific user role to place order without pay woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I want that user having special role assigned can buy product from my store without pay. I searched around and found [Role based shipping/payment](https://woocommerce.com/products/role-based-payment-shipping-methods/) plugin. This plugin works fine for other user role but it do not allow user having special role to place order.

Is there a way to allow only users with special role to place order without any payment and shipping method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you want to disable check out for that prticular role??

Comment: No, i don't want to disable checkout.. I want user fill his details and place order without without any payment or shipping charges. I mean only special user can place order with any payment, rest of the other users will pay and place order. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: ok you mean you have customer role "VPI" .This user role no need to pay anything for buy item.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-samples/ did you check this?

Comment: Yes right.. But the above plugin will not work according to my requirement.. Any other way?

Comment: [wc_rbp id='99' role='VIP' price='regular_price']??

Comment: Modify this file : woocommerce-role-based-price\includes\class-product-functions.php

Comment: Thanks i will check an back to you

Comment: Ok please check you will find solution for sure.

Comment: Hi again, m already using role based plugin to show different prices.. Changes in class-product-function‌​s.php will effect the functionality of plugin ?

Comment: Nope,Just you need to find where is the price is assign to cart.Just put you code there.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify price by this function.Please take backup and perform modifications.

```
public function get_db_price($id){ 
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            if($user->roles[0] == "VIP"){

                return 0;
            }
            else{
            self::$db_prices = get_post_meta($id,'_role_based_price',true );  
            if(is_array(self::$db_prices)){
                return self::$db_prices;
            }
            }
            return false;
        }
```